# fluid-fluid-fluid three columns

Tags: css, fluid-layout

Is it possible to have 3 columns, all equal in width with 2 columns in between, all be fluid? Everything I can find shows one column fixed, or they have different width. I need them all to be the same. No matter what I do on this page, the last li doesn't come all the way to the edge of the container. If I enlarge the % of the li then it doesn't fit in smaller resolutions. Thanks!

[Page example is here](http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/index_new.htm)

[CSS is here](http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/css/kw_styles-responsive2.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it's all about calculating the right percentages.

To start fresh, remove the borders and margins on all three columns. Then make their widths 33.3333% so they will all fit perfectly inside their container.

Looking at your CSS I can see you have a margin (left and right) of 3.75% on the middle column, so you must re-calculate your column widths to 100 - (3.75 * 2) / 3 = 30.833333%.

Secondly, switch your `border` to an `outline` to prevent unnecessary width being added to your layout.

Lastly make your `img`s 100% width so they fit inside their containers nicely.

Should be done after that, I used Firebug to perform all those changes on your site and it looks like it worked out.

Comment: Should probably include a css reset before anything else is applied to keep the browser from applying its arbitrary styling.

Comment: Also you need to be very careful with percentages like that because each browser has [their own rounding implementation](http://agilewebmasters.com/robert/percentage-rounding-and-sub-pixel-perfection/) (can't have half a pixel after all). It's sometimes better to have all your layout percentages add up to something less than 100% to mitigate this

Comment: Thank you that worked! I guess where I'm getting lost is I don't know how to figure out the fluid columns and margins together to equal 100. I did have the image set to max-width=100% but that wasn't working so I switched it to width and not its fixed.

Comment: @Kim- Glad that worked! To note: `max-width` will not actually set the width. It just it _restricts_ the width to a specific size. It also doesn't include margin, borders, or padding.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you already got an answer on how to get it working, but you'll quickly run into another problem if you're going to have any sort of margin or border on these columns.

Those width percentages? They don't include border/margin - so if you add either of those, you'll once again have columns overflow.

Solution? Make sure to set `box-sizing: border-box;` - if you haven't heard of it before, Google it. It's magical!

Answer (score 1):

your question puzzles me a bit. On the one hand, this example shows what you sound like you're asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/JuamW/

On the other hand, the actual example of your site shows a fixed-width situation where your columns have no requirement to be fluid. If the above example doesn't give you what you need, could you provide some more context?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring the last li out add:

```
#categories-wrapper ul li.students{
    float: right;
}

#categories-wrapper ul li.fine-art{
        float:left;
}
```

replace categories-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2) with:

```
#categories-wrapper ul li.gd {
margin-left: 4.25%; /* 36px / 960px */
    float: left;
```

}

And modify this:

```
#categories-wrapper ul li {
    width: 30.20833%; /* 290 / 960 */
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `! important` is bad coding practice. You'd be better off just making your selector more specific so that it is applied instead of other styles.

Comment: That's a good point, you could easily apply a specific class to the first 2 <li's> to eliminate that.